# When Username & password blank Clicking on Login button throws an message, How to Print that message displayed

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver

When Username & Password is Blank, Clicking on Login button throws an message under Username & Password field. I want to Print the message "Password cannot be blank" or "Username cannot be blank". Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEhf5.png)
&
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wku2I.png)

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i used Link text to print it. It throws an exception

Comment: Can you please share your written code? also link text will not help here I think.

Comment: `WebElement ErrorMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Password cannot be blank')]"));
System.out.println("" +ErrorMsg);`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Just FYI, you can green tick only one answer at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following to get text and print of error label :

For Username and Password :

```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'User name cannot be blank')]")).getText());

  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Password name cannot be blank')]")).getText());
```

Hope above will solve your issue.

Comment: @Suguna - By mistake I was missing square bracket to close , I have updated , please check now.

Comment: Thank u @Helping Hands this also helped me

Comment: @Suguna - Great. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching your element by using `contains()` in XPath. I'd suggest to search by class name `label-danger`.

```
List<WebElement> errorMsgs = driver.findElements(By.ByClassName("label-danger"));

for(WebElement e : errorMsgs) {
    System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

This will fetch all the visible warnings displayed to the user and print the message displayed to them.

Comment: Thank u so much. This helped me